# javascript code work in just the first id

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Why javascript code work in just one id?

For example I want to make the first name and the last name first letter to be capital in this form.
I added a javascript code to the `id: "someId"` but it just work in the first text field.
As you can see the first name javascript is working but in the last name it's not

How can I fix it?
Here is my codes

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= render "devise/shared/error_messages", resource: resource %>
    <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :first_name ,"First Name (required)"%>
    <%= f.text_field :first_name, autofocus: true , :size=>"50", required: "true",class: "textbox",placeholder: raw("&#xf007; Your First Name"),id: "someId"%>
  </div><br>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :last_name ,"Last Name (required)"%>
    <%= f.text_field :last_name , :size=>"50", required: "true",class: "textbox",placeholder: raw("&#xf007; Your Last Name"),id: "someId"%>
  </div><br>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :phone ,"Phone (required)"%>
    <%= f.text_field :phone , :size=>"50", required: "true",class: "textbox",placeholder: raw("&#xf095; phone"),id: "phoneNumber"%>
  </div><br>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :address ,"Address (required)"%>
    <%= f.text_field :address , :size=>"50", required: "true",class: "textbox",placeholder: raw("&#xf041; Address"),id: "searchTextField"%>
  </div><br>

  
 

  <div class="field"><br>

     <p class="address"> <%= link_to_add_association "Add more Addresses and Phone numbers", f,:addresses, partial: 'address_fields' %></p>
    </div> 
      <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :image ,"Add Profile Picture"%> <%= f.file_field :image %>
   
 </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.email_field :email, autocomplete: "email" ,class: "textbox",placeholder: raw("&#xf0e0; Your email")%>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <% if @minimum_password_length %>
    <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
    <% end %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "new-password" ,class: "textbox",placeholder: raw("&#xf023 Add a Password")%>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "new-password" ,class: "textbox",placeholder: raw("&#xf023 Password Confirmation")%>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>

</div></div></div>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.1.62/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyA-ATN59uXNYOqQoVajiXKhhN2vsSc9Xb0&libraries=places">
</script>
<!-- You forgot closing this -->
       <!-- You forgot starting the below script tag -->
       <script>
       function initialize() {
         var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
         var options = {componentRestrictions: {country: 'ca'}};            
         new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options); 
       }         
       google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
       </script>

</script>

<style type="text/css">
  .address{
    color: black !important;
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px !important;
  }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#someId").on('keyup', function(e) {
  var arr = $(this).val().split(' ');
  var result = '';
  for (var x = 0; x < arr.length; x++)
    result += arr[x].substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + arr[x].substring(1) + ' ';
  $(this).val(result.substring(0, result.length - 1));
});

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
const isNumericInput = (event) => {
    const key = event.keyCode;
    return ((key >= 48 && key <= 57) || // Allow number line
        (key >= 96 && key <= 105) // Allow number pad
    );
};

const isModifierKey = (event) => {
    const key = event.keyCode;
    return (event.shiftKey === true || key === 35 || key === 36) || // Allow Shift, Home, End
        (key === 8 || key === 9 || key === 13 || key === 46) || // Allow Backspace, Tab, Enter, Delete
        (key > 36 && key < 41) || // Allow left, up, right, down
        (
            // Allow Ctrl/Command + A,C,V,X,Z
            (event.ctrlKey === true || event.metaKey === true) &&
            (key === 65 || key === 67 || key === 86 || key === 88 || key === 90)
        )
};

const enforceFormat = (event) => {
    // Input must be of a valid number format or a modifier key, and not longer than ten digits
    if(!isNumericInput(event) && !isModifierKey(event)){
        event.preventDefault();
    }
};

const formatToPhone = (event) => {
    if(isModifierKey(event)) {return;}

    // I am lazy and don't like to type things more than once
    const target = event.target;
    const input = target.value.replace(/\D/g,'').substring(0,10); // First ten digits of input only
    const areaCode = input.substring(0,3);
    const middle = input.substring(3,6);
    const last = input.substring(6,10);

    if(input.length > 6){target.value = `(${areaCode}) ${middle} - ${last}`;}
    else if(input.length > 3){target.value = `(${areaCode}) ${middle}`;}
    else if(input.length > 0){target.value = `(${areaCode}`;}
};

const inputElement = document.getElementById('phoneNumber');
inputElement.addEventListener('keydown',enforceFormat);
inputElement.addEventListener('keyup',formatToPhone);</script>
```

Comment: Is all this code relevant to the issue?

Comment: an `id` element needs to be unique, don't use the same `id` multiple times, if you need to do that use a class instead.  With an `id` it will grab the first one and then move on because of that rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use class attribute instead id, [rtfm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id)!

Comment: This is how you call a class attribute? document.getElementByClassName

Comment: Yes, also you can use `document.querySelectorAll('.classname')`

Comment: Thank you! For some reason when i replace the id here with class it's working $(".someId").on('keyup', function(e) but in the phone number it's not const inputElement = document.querySelectorAll('phoneNumber'); do you have any idea why?

Comment: cuz you need to append selector like in jquery or css. '.' - for class, '#'-for id, now you trying to find element `<phoneNumber></phoneNumber>`

Comment: I add it but it's still not working const inputElement = document.querySelectorAll('.phoneNumber');

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll` - returns array, try `document.querySelector`